# ADODB Connection fails on Windows10 64 bit with SQL Server 2012

Tags: windows, vb6, sql-server-2012, adodb

Our VB6 application currently is deployed on Windows 7 32-Bit with SQL Server 2008 and is working fine.

We are recently in process of migrating to Windows 10 64-bit with SQL Server 2012 and the following throws an error:

```vb
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.CommandTimeout = 3600 ' 1 hour
conn.Open "DSN=MYDSN" => Error occurs here
```

The DSN has been tested independently and connects to SQL server fine.

The error:

- DNS data=Sql Server &  32 bit or 64 bit of ODBC Datasource:

  > 3709, connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context.
- DNS data source=SQL Server Native Client 11& 32 bit ODBC Datasource:

  > 3709, connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context
- DNS data source: SQL Server Native Client 11 & 64 bit ODBC Datasource:

  > -2147217843, [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database "ClientDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: I assume... you have a 32-bit DSN?

Comment: I tried both 32 and 64 bit DSN. But none of them worked

Comment: It certainly has to be a 32-bit DSN. Does it test correctly from the 32-bit ODBC control panel applet?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My ADODB connection didn't work after I run the same Excel workbook with VBA on a new Windows 10 install. Then I remembered that the same happened when I moved to Windows 8.1 from Windows 7.

The solution on both cases was that the 64-bit version of ODBC simply didn't work out of the box (I don't know why and honestly I didn't bother to debug this).

I know you said you tried the 32-bit version but did you really remove all traces of the 64-bit before trying the 32-bit? Apparently they conflict with each other.

#### Try this steps:

1. Remove any 64-bit DSN which uses the relevant 64-bit ODBC driver. Do
   this from *ODBC Data Sources (64-bit)* Control Panel
2. Uninstall the 64-bit driver.
3. Install the 32-bit driver.
4. Configure DSN (obviously from *ODBC Data Sources (32-bit)* Control
   Panel)

Try again...

My problem was with VBA in Excel and the connection used MySQL ODBC Driver to connect to MySql DB but it might be the same issue.